# Position of image changes on resizing the window

Tags: html, css, layout, styling, window-resize

```css
.pinkDiv {
       position: relative;
       width: 100%;
       height: 40vh;;
       background-color: pink;
    }

    .miniDiv {
       position:relative;
    }

    .p1 {
       position:absolute;
    }
```

```html
<div class="pinkDiv">
     <div class ="miniDiv">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/ff00ff/fff.png" class = "p1" style="background-color:green;">
     </div>
    </div>
```

The position of the image changes, when I resize the browser window. I want it to stick to the pink div on top and move with it as I resize the window. I also tried assigning position relative to pink div and mini div and position absolute to img, nothing works.
So, this is what I have (also see attached pictures):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3w6n.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvwwg.png

On running the code snippet in the comment section and resizing the window:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jgIy.png

Comment: Can you post your css? Just checking the pics maybe if you set the width with percentage it can get better.

Comment: @FabioAssuncao posted!!

Comment: @DhvaniKhakhar So you want to fix the image on the top?

Comment: @DhvaniKhakhar Do you to fix pinkDiv or sticky pinkDiv?

Comment: @RevtiShah I want to place the image of the pawn such that the bottom of the pawn, that is, the end of the image aligns with the end of the pink div. I can use margin-top for that. The problem is, when I resize the window, the position of the image changes completely and doesn't align with the pink div anymore- as you can see in the 2 link images I've attached.

Comment: @DhvaniKhakhar Got it. Have you given width:100% to img?

Comment: @RevtiShah on doing so, the image covers the whole webpage

Comment: <img src="./Images/pawn.png" class = "p1" style="background-color:green;width:100%;">

Comment: @DhvaniKhakhar but you have to give width on upper div.

Comment: @RevtiShah where do you suggest I put the "width:100%"?

Comment: @DhvaniKhakhar Wait i will put the code. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @RevtiShah Appreciate it!! Thank you

Comment: @DhvaniKhakhar Please check the below code which I posted.

Comment: @RevtiShah thank you!! However, when I resize the window, the image remains the same size and overflows out of the pinkDiv - i'm trying to contain the image in the pink div. I've edited my main question so i could attach a link of my window in the main question. Your code is link number 3

Comment: @RevtiShah yes i'll check now 1 second thank you

Comment: Oh I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @DhvaniKhakhar Where?

Comment: @DhvaniKhakhar Wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code. Please check it. Hope it will help you. If any changes then please let me know.

```css
.pinkDiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.miniDiv {
  width:100px;
}

img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="pinkDiv">
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/ff00ff/fff.png" class="p1" style="background-color:green;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! However, when I resize the window, the image remains the same size and flows out of the pink div.

Comment: @DhvaniKhakhar Even I updated code. Please check. And if I am right then please give me feedback.

Comment: @DhvaniKhakhar Hard Refresh the page  and check it.

Comment: when we say img {width:100%}, we're asking it to cover 100% of the window width

Comment: Ma'am, your code works amazingly!! Thank you!! My only issue now is that when i resize the window, all the text gets perfectly resized with the window, however, the size of the image remains the same and big, causing it to look disproportionate. Is there anyway that when I resize the window, the image also accordingly gets smaller?

Comment: @DhvaniKhakhar then you have to use media query in CSS. then you can resize the image size.

Comment: Anyway you can guide me as to how to use that in code? Youtube doesn't have much :/

Comment: @DhvaniKhakhar yeah sure definitely.

Comment: @DhvaniKhakhar Are you new in CSS?

Comment: Thank you!! Yes, I am new at css!!

Comment: Then you should follow this link  https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Comment: @DhvaniKhakhar I will help you wherever you need me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.p1 
{
  width: 100%
}
```